What is the latest and greatest way to migrate from cvs to git?
I have been reading all over the internet about how to migrate from CVS to git; mostly using a tool cvs2git. However, all of the posts and documentation are really old, and there are dead links for where to download this tool.
So, refreshing this old question: What is the latest and greatest method for wholesale migrating a cvs server to a git server? Like, if I have direct access to the server (running windows), what can I do? If it matters at all, this is for migration to gitlab self hosted


Using cvs2git is relatively simple but that can depend on the complexity of your project.

mkdir /tmp/{cvs,git}
cp -a /path/to/cvs-repo /tmp/cvs
cd /tmp/git
git init
cvs2git --blobfile=blob.dat --dumpfile=dump.dat --root=/path/to/cvs-repo /tmp/cvs
git fast-import < dump.dat


In this section, gitlab references some other tools :
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/import/cvs.html#how-to-migrate

